# xen server edition - need more cores for win7 VMs

Tags: windows-7, xen

I setup a win7 VM in my Xen 6.2 system with 8 cores. When the VM boots it only shows 2 cores (and the performance seems to go along with this).

Looking at the docs for Xen it seems that this limitation used to be imposed on customers who took the free edition vs the 'platinum','gold', etc. But now that Xen is entirely open source these editions are gone.

So is it possible to get more cores in a win7 VM now?

Comment: I've never seen that problem... I have 4 cores showing on mine.

Comment: It has me puzzled for certain. I have a number of Win7 (pro) VMs running. Going through them I note that all show 2 cores (in task mgr).

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 7 Pro only supports (2) discrete CPU sockets** so make sure you have allocated the cores over 2 sockets or less.

In my case, I ran quickly through the settings and allocated 4 vCPUs over 4 sockets with 1 core per socket; only 2 of the 4 cores showed up in the VM.  When I changed to the cores being in a single socket, all 4 cores were visible and usable in the VM.

I know this years later, but I just experienced this and figured I would share.